# Wordpress wp_get_current_user() not showing result

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm just testing some PHP to try and find out what role a user has because I want to try and do the following:

```
foreach($current_user->roles as $key => $value){
    if($value == ''){
        $npl= true;
    }
}
```

Basically updating `$npl` to true if no user role is chosen.

The code below only returns `Array` when it should be showing me a fair bit more than that.

```
<?php

include 'wp-blog-header.php';

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_id = $current_user->ID;
$user = new WP_User( $user_id );

echo "id:" . $current_user;

        foreach($current_user->roles as $key => $value){
            if($value == ''){
                echo "yes";
            }
            else {
                echo "no";
            }
        }

print_r(array_values($user->roles));

?>
```

[image: array]

I've tried at several stages to make it work but showing the id early isn't showing anything either

## EDIT

I even tried:

```
<?php

include '../wp-blog-header.php';
include '../includes/wp-load.php';
include_once('../wp-config.php');

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_id = $current_user->ID;

echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . '<br />';
echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';
echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . '<br />';
echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . '<br />';
echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . '<br />';

foreach($current_user->roles as $key => $value){
    if($value == ''){
        echo "yes" . '<br />';
    }
    else {
        echo "no" . '<br />';
    }
}

print_r(array_values($current_user->roles));

echo '<br />' . "The time is " . date("h:i:sa");

?>
```

Comment: What php/wordpress version do you have? Your code is not compatible with your result. `wp_get_current_user` returns an object, so your above script doesn't output “Array”. It produce a fatal error (Object of class WP_User could not be converted to string). Are you sure that code in example is the same that you are using?

Comment: Latest wordpress, it doesn't return an fatal error, it outputs what I showed you in the screenshot.

Comment: See [WP Func Ref](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user): “Retrieve the current user object”. Also, why “id:” is not displayed?

Comment: @fusion3k See the following http://i.imgur.com/8OqKYI5.png, still not working and yes I am logged in.

Comment: As expected, it is not above output. It is correct. It means that the selected user has not particular roles. `Array` ≠ `Array()` (try it with admin user to see the difference).

Comment: It isn't correct, it should be outputting username, user, displayname... etc but it isn't I am logged in with an admin user and I have also tried a normal member.

Answer (score 1):

Please `include` `wp-load.php` and load file is on root. So please include load file

The simplest way to require/include wp-load.php

If you want to use WordPress functionality in a PHP file that exists outside of your WordPress installation then you need to include wp-load.php. Perhaps you could call this “hooking into WordPress”.

Maybe you’re already using some sort of relative path method, like:

But this can create problems if directories change. You need a clean, dynamic way to get wp-load.php. So here is the simplest way to do it, with just two lines of code (place it at the very top of your file):

```
<?php include '../../../wp-load.php'; ?>
```

Short and sweet :)

Disclaimer: This is intended for experimental and development purposes only. It is not advised to redundantly load WordPress on live production environments. But, why?

Comment: It doesn't appear to work, still the same output. It doesn't matter about the location as I am only running it/this as a test at the moment, once I know it works I will be adding it into a plugin which already has the `$current_user`

Answer (score 1):

There is error in your code try this:

```
<?php

include 'wp-blog-header.php';

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_id = $current_user->ID;
$user = new WP_User( $user_id );

echo "id:" . $user_id;

    foreach($current_user->roles as $key => $value){
        if($value == ''){
            echo "yes";
        }
        else {
            echo "no";
        }
    }

    print_r(array_values($current_user->roles));

  ?>
```

You are calling  `$current_user` directly which gives array as output.

Comment: nope, the array comes from the print at the bottom. `echo $current_user;` returns nothing. The output of your code is returning `id:0Array ( )` which is wrong, the id of the account I am logged into is 1 and the array should have `administrator` in it.

Comment: try including `include_once(path/to/wordpress/wp-config.php)` . This will load wordpress functions.

Comment: where is file located or can you tell me the file structure.

Comment: The file is located in a correct folder `/public_html/testfolder/test.php` for my example above

Comment: try using full url like this ...  `include 'http://yoursite.com/wp-blog-header.php';`

Answer (score 0):

I got your question and since yet, no one gave you the correct answer, i have what your are looking for. I used it recently on the WP API to give sensible access to some users based on if the current-user has the appropriate permission. Here is my code.

```
function check_user_role(){

global $ne;

//check current user capabilities to determin the role type he pocess
if (!current_user_can('activate_plugins')) {
    $ne =  "Subscriber";
} else {
    $ne =  "admintrator";
}

$infos = array(
    'role' => $ne
);

return $ne;
}

echo check_user_role();
```

I hope it will help you. ☻☻☻☻